# Count values above a range of thresholds

Tags: r

I have a data frame of values and want to count the number of values in each column that are greater than or equal to a series of thresholds. The ultimate goal is to produce a graph that looks like panels B and D in this figure [image: graphs]

I have figured out a way to do this with a `for` loop but would like to avoid a loop if possible:

```
data <- as.data.frame(attitude)
max <- 100
counts <- data.frame(t(c(score = 1, colSums(data >= 1))))
for (x in 2:max) {
  counts <- rbind(counts, c(score = x, colSums(data >= x)))
}
```

I tried adapting the code from this question ([Count the number of values per column above a range of thresholds in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66130168/count-the-number-of-values-per-column-above-a-range-of-thresholds-in-r)), but it gives an error and does not produce the expected result:

```
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  lapply(
    function(z) table(findInterval(z, 0:max, rightmost.closed = TRUE))
  ) %>% 
  do.call(cbind, .) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Is there a way to do this without a loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `sapply`/`lapply` :

```
data <- as.data.frame(attitude)
num <- seq_len(100)

result <- data.frame(score = num, 
                     do.call(rbind, lapply(num, function(x) colSums(data >= x))))
```